# String includes set of object how to get object

Tags: reactjs

```
string="hello coimbatore @{name:Abilene,locality:Abilene,TX,USA} hello coimbatore @{name:Abilene,locality:Abilene,TX,USA}"


value=[{name:Abilene,locality:Abilene,TX,USA},{name:Abilene,locality:Abilene,TX,USA}]
```

Get it now how to get ?

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: @Gowri did you check my answer?

Comment: @Apostolos your answers is good

Comment: let string = "hello coimbatore madurai A paragraph is a series of related sentences developing a central idea, called the topic. Try to think about paragraphs in terms of thematic unity: a paragraph is a sentence or a   @{name:Abilene,locality:Abilene,TX,USA} coimbatore chennai  @{name:Abilene,locality:Abilene,TX,USA}A paragraph is a series of related sentences developing a central idea, called the topic.@{name:Abilene,locality:Abilene,TX,USA} Try to think about paragraphs in terms of thematic unity: a paragraph is a sentence or a  "

Comment: how to get object @Apostolos

Comment: please post another question and the code you tried. thnx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult since string does not point to a valid json object but with a little bit of "dirty" code, you can achieve it.
You first split the string and then use splice in order to get rid of the first empty entry inside the split array.

Then, since json cant parse the strings, you need to insert double quotes, so as JSON to be able to consider it as a valid json object and successfully parse it.

```js
let string = "hello coimbatore @{name:Abilene,locality:Abilene,TX,USA} hello coimbatore @{name:Abilene,locality:Abilene,TX,USA}"
let arr1 = string.split('hello coimbatore @')
arr1 = arr1.splice(1, string.length)
let arr2 = arr1.map(t => t = JSON.parse(t.replaceAll('{', '{"').replaceAll(',locality', '","locality').replaceAll(':', '":"').replaceAll('}', '"}')))
console.log(arr2)
```